# Enable color decorators in comments in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code color decorators work fine on normal code (like in CSS files). But it doesn't show up in the comments, like the image below:

[image: A screenshot of comments in CSS]

How can I make VS Code show the color decorators in comments as well?

PS: The setting for color decorators is `"editor.colorDecorators": true`.

Comment: write your own decorator provider and parse the comments for colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible.

The way the feature works is that the decorators are placed next to CSS colour values, as determined by the parser (by default, [VS Code CSS Lanugage Service](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice)). However the parser treats all text within comments as text, not parseable code.